# Getting lookup view model to trigger Modal Dialog

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, binding

What's the right way to get my viewmodel to trigger a custom lookup control to throw up a modal dialog that essentially represents that lookup viewmodel? The custom lookup control's data context is that of the parent record view model.  The lookup control also has another DependencyProperty that has it bound to a lookupviewmodel property on the parent record view model and this represents a sub lookupviewmodel.

METHOD 1) I currrently use an event on the lookupviewmodel that the custom control knows to listen for.

METHOD 2) I tried throwing a validation exception within the setter of the property on the lookupviewmodel that the lookup control's text propery is bound too.  Then I hooked the ErrorEvent in the custom lookup control.  But it seems that if the user "corrects" the value from within the dialog while in this event, the original value sticks.  And worse, even after I call Validation.ClearInvalid, another ErrorEvent still fires that somehow adds the error back. So everything works here in the sense that all the viewmodels have the correct data, it's just that it seems like the textbox is ignoring that the bound text property has changed on the underlying data source when inside an ErrorEvent. So it seems like I can't correct an error while inside the processing of that error?

Another sub issue within method 2 is that Validation.ClearInvalid doesn't remove the red error border.  I had to manually clear the ErrorTemplate too. Is that right?

I'd like to find a way to use natural error handling within the control to get it to throw up the modal dialog.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This isn't what you use events for.  Events exist to facilitate decoupling:  the object raising the event shouldn't know or care what the object(s) listening to it are doing.  You're expecting an event to be able to change the value of a property from inside the property's setter - or worse, your event handler is calling the very property setter that's raising the event that it's handling, which means that you have to do something pretty hackish to avoid a stack overflow.

Your description isn't very clear (you're describing both the problem you're having and the non-working solutions you're trying at the same time, which is confusing), but it sounds like what you're trying to do is something more like:

```
if (IsValid(value))
{
   _Property = value;
}
else
{
   _Property = GetValueFromDialog();
}
```

The problem is that you don't want to have code in your view model that throws up a dialog, since that creates a view model that can't be tested outside of your WPF application.

The answer in this case is to use dependency injection.  Create an interface called `IDialogService`:

```
interface IDialogService
{
   object GetValueFromDialog();
}
```

Now add this property to your view model:

```
public IDialogService DialogService { get; set; }
```

The above code becomes:

```
if (IsValid(value))
{
   _Property = value;
}
else
{
   _Property = DialogService.GetValueFromDialog();
}
```

Create a dialog service for use in your WPF application that actually throws up the dialog and gets the result.  When you instantiate your view model in your application, do this:

```
MyViewModel vm = new MyViewModel { DialogService = new WpfDialogService(); }
```

Thus, in your application, the property setter will put up the dialog and get the result exactly as you expect it to.

For your unit tests, create a mock dialog that looks like this:

```
public class MockDialogService : IDialogService
{
   private object Result;

   public MockDialogService(object result)
   {
      Result = result;
   }

   public object GetValueFromDialog() { return Result; }
}
```

You can then write a test like:

```
MyViewModel vm = new MyViewModel { DialogService = MockDialogService(ExpectedResult) };
vm.Property = InvalidValue;
Assert.AreEqual(ExpectedResult, vm.Property);
```

The above is really more a sketch of a solution than a solution - depending on how your application uses dialogs, you may need a lot more features than what are sketched out here.  If you take a look at MVVM frameworks you'll find that a lot of them implement dialog services of one kind or another.

Comment: I've read about DialogService and even Mediator. I'm guess I'm just torn especially given how much debate there is on this topic. Who should be responsible for throwing up GUI elements, views or viewmodels?  If I use the DialogService, then no matter what or where or what control is used, is the property setter fails, it will throw up a dialog. And what if the designer doesn't implement a dialog? I was trying to come up with a way to have the viewmodels not care in any way shape or form about gui elements.  They validate, and it it fails, the view decides if it wants to take action.

Comment: I'll probably eventually need DialogService for other types of dialogs but I didn't want to give up so easily for validation lookup dialogs. What I've done now is my LookupViewModel has a bool ShowModalDialog propery that the custom lookup control is monitoring via INotifyProperyChanged.  If validation fails, the lookup view model sets this to true and the modal appears and the user can pick a new value or cancel. The dialog result makes it back to the property setter that set ShowModalDialog to true and it the result is anything but true, it throws the validation exception.

Comment: The view model requests the dialog and handles the response.  The WPF dialog service is essentially part of the view.  The concerns are well separated:  the view model knows nothing about how the dialog is implemented, it just knows that it wants a response from the user and gets it.

Comment: The problem is that via the DialogService, the viewmodel at least needs to know that a value is expected back. And what if multiple properties need to be returned? What I'm liking about this current version is that the LookupViewModel is now able to trigger the modal to show up and that data (user selection) makes it's way back into the models through the normal binding/command mechanism.  I guess in way, my custom lookup control is just a type of one way dialog service trigger in itself, just one tailered for lookups.

Comment: However, what is expected for testing? With the dialog service, one needs to mock the dialog.  With my current implementation,I don't need to mock anything and I can test that validation fails and I can test that validation passes.

Comment: If it works, it works.  But I have to say that you've created kind of a worst-case scenario of a property setter that triggers a side effect.  Not only does the code `ShowModalDialog = true` (non-obviously) raise an event, it's triggering manipulation of the VM's properties by some other object's code.  I don't see how this approach makes it any easier to test, either - mocking a dialog service isn't harder than writing an event handler, and - critically - the code in your view's event handler may have bugs that the code in your unit test's event handler doesn't.

Comment: I'm confused. What's the difference between a property setter doing validation and either calling a dialogservice or setting a property? My 'concern' with the DialogService is that now the ViewModel is the one deciding to explicity throw up a dialog, NOT the view. I was wanting a way that the ViewModel could properly do it's validation and if necessary provide a mechanism that the view could, if it wanted to, throw up a modal to allow the user to correct the validation. If the view didn't want to, well, the control would just render with it's red border and show the validation error.

Comment: I guess one of my biggest questions with MVVM is what part, the V or the VM, should decide on the flow of screens trhough the GUI? Seems like DialogService is now basically coding GUI workflow into the VMs, just that it's abstracted.

Comment: I don't think there's a problem with GUI workflow being coded into the VM.  I mean, not as far as the primary design concerns of MVVM are concerned.  Workflow and presentation are distinct concerns - indeed, I can envision scenarios in which you'd abstract workflow out to its own set of services.  As far as theming your view is concerned, you accomplish the change you describe with different dialog services - the view still decides which service to use.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a framework like MVVMLight or Prism which allow you to pass payloads between different entities in totally decoupled ways. MVVMLight is very lightweight compared to Prism. It has a concept of Messanger which acts as a system wide event bus. Similarly you have EventAggregator in Prism.